# Integer partitioning in Java

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming, partitioning, integer-partition

I'm trying to implement a program that returns the number of existing partitions of an integer n as part of an assignment. I wrote the code below, but it returns the wrong number (Partitions n returns the result of Partitions n-1). I don't get why this happens. I've tried many things and still don't know how to fix it, can anyone please help me?

```
[edited code out to avoid plagiarism from my colleagues :p]
```

m stands for the biggest number allowed in a partition, so partition(4,4) would be 5 = 4, 3+1, 2+2, 2+1+1, 1+1+1+1, but partition (4,1) would be 1 = 1+1+1+1.
Execution: java Partitions n

Comment: @JacobG. A partition of a positive integer n is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers. Two sums that differ only in the order of their summands are considered the same partition. more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: `else if (n <= 1 | m == 1)` should probably be `else if (n <= 1 || m == 1)`

Comment: @KevinO that should not affect the program's behavior

Comment: You've written `partition` as a function of two integers `n` and `m` (besides the memoization array, which also stores a function of two integers).  I'm sure you had a good reason for this, but the rest of us don't know what the definition of your `partition(n,m)` is.

Comment: I'm editing the question to clarify it. m stands for the biggest number in the partition, so partition(5, 5) would be 7 =  5, 4 +1, ... 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 and partition (5, 1) would be 1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 I did it because the assignment is a derivation from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Partition.java.html and they do that there

Comment: Please also make sure you clarify how the above function is called.  If we want to find what `partitions(n)` is, we'll need to set up a memoization array and then call your function with `partitions(n,???,memo)`.  The big question is, what is the first value of that second parameter?  We need to know in order to understand your code and give you an answer.

Comment: @ajb done, added the main function to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you're calling `partitions(4,4,memo)`.  As you said, the answer should be 5 because there are 5 ways to partition the integer:

```
4
3 + 1           <== counted by partition(1,3,memo)
2 + 2           <== counted by partition(2,2,memo)
2 + 1 + 1       <== counted by partition(2,2,memo)
1 + 1 + 1 + 1   <== counted by partition(3,1,memo)
```

So it looks like your algorithm tries to count the partitions in the way shown above... but is there one partition you're forgetting to count?

Comment: Please be careful about how you fix it--my first attempt didn't work when I tried it.  In particular, `partition(4,2)` needs to return 3.

Comment: the simple way to solve it would be adding 1 to n right after parsing it in main, but i'm guessing that's the lazy way. i'm trying to find another one now